# Perl - printing output after a for loop

Tags: perl, for-loop

I have this code where I have problem getting the output I want:

```
print OUT1 "$first[0]\t$first[1]\t$first[2]\t";
for my $index1 (3..8)
{
  my $ratio1 = sprintf( "%.4f%s", $numerator/$denominator,"\t");
  #print OUT1 "$ratio1";
  $variable1 = "$ratio1"; # problem with this line  
} 

print OUT1 "$variable1";  # print to textfile
print OUT1 "\n";
```

I am trying to print out the output after it run finish the for loop 6 times (3 to 8). The data should arrange something like this:

Desired output (e.g.):

```
       A  B  C  4  4  4  4  4   4
       C  D  F  2  6  5  8  3   1
       G  H  I  6  1  2  4  7   0
```

Instead, it print out only the last column:

```
        A  B  C  4
        C  D  F  1
        G  H  I  0
```

so I change to this line by adding the "." to join the 6 columns together

```
        $variable1 .= "$ratio1"; # problem with this line
```

and I get weird output like this:

```
        A  B  C  4  4  4  4  4  4
        A  B  C  4  4  4  4  4  4  2  6  
        A  B  C  4  4  4  4  4  4  2  6  4 
        A  B  C  4  4  4  4  4  4  2  6  4  6 
        A  B  C  4  4  4  4  4  4  2  6  4  6  1 ...
```

Is there anything wrong with my code somewhere?

Comment: Why don't you just print `$ratio` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to declare and initialize your `$variable1` before your for loop

```
print OUT1 "$first\t$second\t$third\t";
my $variable1 = '';
for my $index1 (3..8)
{
    $variable1 .= sprintf( "%.4f%s", $numerator/$denominator,"\t");
}
print OUT1 "$variable1";  # print to textfile
```

Alternatively, you could avoid a temporary buffer, and just print within the for loop

Comment: Hi yes..I did declared and initialize my $variable1 before my for loop actually.

I wanted to print out of for loop because I need to take the $variable1 for other calculation outside for loop. I print out $variable1 for the purpose of checking if the output is ok. :)

Comment: The you need to save all of your intermediate values in a list for later use and ultimately, printing

Comment: Hi, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want me to write it for you?